# how to use Orderby in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am trying to order data in accordance with its priority...
But this query is not working for me....
I cannot figure it out where it went wrong..

please help me to solve this..

```
$admins = $this->xxx->find()
    ->select($fields)
    ->where($conditions)
    ->contain([
        'yyy' => function ($q) {   
            return $q->autoFields(false)
                ->select(['id','name','login_url','priority'])
                ->order(['priority' => 'ASC']);
            }
    ])
    ->all();
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Please be more specific, and explain what exactly happens (what does the generated SQL look like, what data do you receive, etc...), and what exactly you expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 3):

If the realtionship between xxx and yyy is belongsTo then you have to move the order() method outside the contain

```
$admins = $this->xxx->find()
    ->select($fields)
    ->where($conditions)
    ->contain([
        'yyy' => function ($q) {   
            return $q->autoFields(false)
                ->select(['id','name','login_url','priority']);
            }
    ])
    ->order(['yyy.priority' => 'ASC'])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    //array of field names
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
    //string or array defining order
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
    'group' => array('Model.field'), // fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset' => n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
    'having' => array('COUNT(Model.field) >' => 1), // fields to HAVING by
    'lock' => true // Enable FORM UPDATE locking
)
```